# Dynamically bind data to dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

How to dynamically bind data to `<%Html.Dropdownlist....` in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 15):

Just pass the correct IEnumerable as the typed model or ViewData. Try something like this (out of my head):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(string.Empty, 
    "myDropDownList",  
    new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["stuff"], 
        "DescriptionProperty", 
        "ValueProperty")) 
%>
```

With that drop down list helper in MVC, you do not really "bind" data to it in the way it is done in the old ASP.NET.